# 'byte[] com.squareup.wire.ProtoAdapter.encode(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

Tags: android

[Please refer screenshot in this link, Couldn't find the proper root cause of the null pointer exception.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhklU.png)

Comment: Add the error in the question itself, and also the minimal reproducible code. See how to ask a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: What is at line 92 and how is your `Message` object initialised?